# Can't create a vector map with VectorTopo in new mapset after switching

Tags: python, grass-gis, pygrass

I need to create vector maps in different mapsets with pygrass. However, there seems to be a "hidden" global variable which prevents mapset in pygrass from changing. It sort of "memorizes" the mapset the first time when `VectorTopo` is called. The global variable does not change after subsequent `g.mapset` calls. The following code snipet can be used to reproduce the issue.

```
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import general as g
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import vector as v
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import raster as r
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import database as db
from grass.pygrass.vector import geometry as Geo
from grass.pygrass.vector import VectorTopo

# Create a vector map with one point in the first mapset
g.mapset('test1', flags='c')
new = VectorTopo('newvect', mapset='test1')
new.open('w')
pt = Geo.Point(0, 0)
new.write(pt)
new.close()


# Then switch the mapset
g.mapset('test2', flags='c')

#new2 still points to the "newvect" map in the "test1" mapset even
#though mapset is set to 'test2'
new2 = VectorTopo('newvect', mapset='test2') 

new2.open('w') 

pt2 = Geo.Point(0, 0)
new2.write(pt2)

#the program crashes because VectorTopo tries to build the map in
#mapset 'test2' but 'new2' is pointing to the "newvect" in mapset 'test1'
new2.close()
```

In the source code of the `VectorTopo` class, the `mapinfo` attribute is initilized with `self.c_mapinfo = ctypes.pointer(libvect.Map_info())`. For some reason, the value of mapset is fixed once `VectorTopo` is called. Any idea how to change the "hidden" global variable?